# IOS import error

Tags: ios, facebook, api

I'm really new to IOS and I just started to use the API-Graph of Facebook.

Now I want to do the "/me" query but I got this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequest'

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
....
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

if ((error) != nil)
{
    // Process error
}
else if result.isCancelled {
    // Handle cancellations
}
else {  
    if result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_friends") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_posts") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_photos")
    {
        //HERE IS MY QUERY

        let params = ["fields" : "email, name"]
        let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)  <-- HERE I GOT THE ERROR
        graphRequest.start {
            (urlResponse, requestResult) in

            switch requestResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("error in graph request:", error)
                break
            case .success(let graphResponse):
                if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                    print(responseDictionary)

                    print(responseDictionary["name"])
                    print(responseDictionary["email"])
                }
            }
        }


                guard let presentedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "01") else { return }
                presentedController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.partialCurl
                self.present(presentedController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }


        guard let presentedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "01") else { return }
        presentedController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.partialCurl
        self.present(presentedController, animated: true, completion: nil)*/
    }else{
        //cambia stato bottone
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Permission", message: "We need all the permission for continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

I did the Import and the FB Login work good. What I did wrong? (I'm using Swift 3)

Update 2:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphRequest` should instead be `FBSDKGraphRequest`.

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
```

**Note:** In addition to the iOS SDK, there is also a Swift specific SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift

**EDIT:**

Based on your updated question, it appears that `FBSDKGraphRequest` can return an optional. An optional means that you will either get an instance of `FBSDKGraphRequest` or `nil`.

You can handle an optional in a few different ways.

- Using a `guard` construct
- Using the `if let` construct
- Using `?`

Using `guard`:

```
guard let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params) else {
    // Handle the fact that graphRequest is nil
}

graphRequest.start { ... } // graphRequest is guaranteed to be not nil
```

Using `if let`:

```
if let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params) {
    graphRequest.start { ... } // graphRequest is guaranteed to be not
} else {
    // Handle the fact that graphRequest is nil
}
```

Using `?`:

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)

graphRequest?.start { ... }
```

This would silently do nothing if `graphRequest` is `nil`.

**EDIT 2:**

You appear to be calling the `start` method using the Facebook Swift SDK way instead of their iOS SDK way.

`FBSDKGraphRequestHandler` is a `typedef` that is defined with the following parameters:

- `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection` connection
- `id` result
- `NSError` error

So when calling `start`, you need to account for these parameters in the closure.

```
graphRequest.start { connection, result, error in
    ...
}
```

or use `_` for the parameters that you are *not* interested in.

```
graphRequest.start { _, result, _ in
    ...
}
```

**NOTE:** Your `switch` statement will likely not work with the code above. You will need to make further changes to get it working with the parameters that are provided (connection, result and error). Again, it appears that you may be mixing Facebook's Swift SDK code and iOS SDK code.

Comment: Seem fixed but got an error after that line, question updated with the screen

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Sadly got another one, I'm trying to fix it.... answer updated, any tips?

Comment: @GMX I've updated my answer. However, it seems that you are mixing code from Facebook's Swift SDK and iOS SDK. This will likely lead to other errors. Since you seem to be using the iOS SDK, then you should ensure that your code works with that SDK. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

Comment: @GMX If you are not particular about which SDK, then using the Swift SDK might be better suited. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift

Comment: Now I know why this error, I'll try to use Swift SDK, Thank you, you explained really well